# Docker postgres connection from *inside* docker container to host machine's postgres localhost instance on a Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker

All the questions on SO about this seem to refer to an opposite case of creating a postgres *container* and connecting it from Mac host. But I am trying to do the opposite, without success. I have localhost running on my Mac host machine, and despite setting port flags, I cannot get code inside my container to talk to my localhost postgres (talks to remote host postgres just  fine).

```
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 -p 5432:5432 yard-stats
```

Then inside docker:

```
telnet 0.0.0.0 5432
Trying 0.0.0.0...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

or telnet 127.0.0.1 or localhost. Connection is refused.

Edit:  I also tried with flag `--network="host"`, which did not change anything except break inbound connections to the container on localhost:5000 as well.

Comment: Try to telnet to the docker bridge's IP in most cases the IP is 172.17.0.1 so:
"telnet 172.17.0.1 5432"
To find the docker bridge IP address type: "ip a|grep docker0"

Comment: I tried that, no dice. But thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using docker for mac, you can use use `host.docker.internal` special DNS name which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host.

---

You can also use `--network="host"` with your docker run command to run the container in host network. Then the `localhost` interface inside the container will be same as `localhost` interface of the host machine when run in host network. So you should be able to use `localhost:5432` to connect to postgresql. You can remove `-p` option as it has no effect when running with `--network="host"`.

`docker run -it --network=host yard-stats`

Comment: Hey `host.docker.internal` works! I just need to tell postgres to accept that dns as it seems blocked for postgres but not for telnet. That `network="host"` flag did not work.

Comment: To be precise I get this error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist``` Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out--I was using a blank username on localhost!